# Estimate transfer function of dc motor

Tags: matlab, nidaqmx

I have a motor generator set-up (two shaft coupled RS380PH DC Motors) and a driver circuit (TL071CP). I want to estimate their collective transfer function using MATLAB, a NI-DAQ. I think the best way to do this is using the function sys = tfest(data,np) where data is the data gathered from a few step response tests. Should I gather the data using iddata (time estimation) or frd / idfrd (frequency domain estimation)? Does anyone have experience doing this with a NI-DAQ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [estimate transfer function from input output data matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18684436/estimate-transfer-function-from-input-output-data-matlab)